# Why is 'The toilets are cleaned every day by a cleaner' incorrect?

Tags: passive-voice

I don't know why my book claims the sentence:

> The toilets are cleaned every day by a cleaner.

is incorrect. I took this sentence from my exercise book. The instruction is indentifying whether the sentence is correct. The answer key says it's incorrect. It's in the chapter about passive sentences, by the way. There's no further detail as well.

Isn't the original sentence:

> A cleaner cleans the toliets every day. ?

Where's the mistake?

I've checked the definition of **cleaner**. A cleaner can be a person or a machine that being used for cleaning something. However does it matter which is which?

Comment: I agree, the sentence is not wrong. I might choose **janitor** or **custodian** over **cleaner** but the grammar is fine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about an inaccurate claim made in a substandard exercise book (there's nothing wrong with the cited text).

Comment: @randomhead that's a US vs. UK thing I think (and many much of the Commonwealth would be likely to follow the UK).  "[Custodian](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/custodian)" would be unheard of in British English, at least in this context, while "janitor" would be more of an acceptable Americanism. In the UK "cleaner" is specific, while a school or similar institution may have a "caretaker" who also does minor maintenance jobs

Comment: You could say that 'the toilets are cleaned every day by a cleaner' is not very elegant because -- who else would clean something but a cleaner? In the same way, 'this plank is whacked every day by a plank whacker' is inelegant (because it repetitively states the obvious).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I disagree that 'cleaner' is necessarily redundant.  In a workplace, or even a residence, that has no one employed as a cleaner the toilets may be cleaned, perhaps on a rota, by other members of staff. This could certainly be true of a new cooperative which was trying to save as much money as possible.

Comment: @BoldBen - when I use the toilet in a supermarket, bus station, branch of Starbucks, wherever, I might be interested or reassured to know that it is cleaned every day. I think the organisational details, e.g. whether it is done by a cleaner or disgraced software developer undergoing ritual punishment, are less vital. Anyhow, someone who cleans a toilet is a cleaner at the time.